# Gremlin-Server Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, titan, gremlin, tinkerpop3

I am starting to work with Titan and I am using cassandra as backend store.

When I start titan.sh cassandra and elasticsearch were started but the gremlin server did not.

I was looking at titan.sh and I have seen that it start gremlin server with conf/gremlin-server/gremlin-server.yaml. The problem is that the gremlin-server.yaml is configured as this:
graphs: {
graph: conf/gremlin-server/titan-berkeleyje-server.properties}

Using BerkeleyDb. I have not seen the cassandra.yaml for Gremlin Server.

How can I configure the it for Cassandra ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

A fix from Stephen has been checked in to address this https://github.com/thinkaurelius/titan/commit/89c0a2b30e798a13e098949c219730b228bcc82a

Comment: As soon as I can access my development machine I will make the update.Thank you very much.